# mate weather indication stopped working

Tags: 14.04, indicator, mate, weather

some time ago, the service used by weather indicator was shut down: http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/08/gnome-weather-forecast-not-available

but there is no update or fix. so my question is: how can i make it working again? is there some ppa? or some instructions to install the fixed version from source? or some config file edit?

i'm using ubuntu 14.04, mate, Weather Report 1.8.1